# How to replace a specific position of a string while the position is changing

Tags: java

Hi I'm a novice coder and I've been up all night trying to figure this out.
I'm working on a hangman game where the user has to input the letter they want to guess with and the number of spaces they want to check. The word is of course hidden by dashes. When the user gets a letter correct in the right space i'm suppose to print out the hidden word with the letters and spaces guessed correctly. for example

Word: loops

Hidden: -----

What letter would you like to guess:
o

Which spaces would you like to check:
1 2

Hidden: -oo--

I know that Strings are immutable so I have to create a new string and concatinate it with the substring and the letter that user inputed but the position changes so I have to re order how  I concatinate it every time correct?

And I'm not allowed to use arrays, StringBuilder, or StringBuffer

I hope I explained this clear enough

here is what I've done so far

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter your difficulty: Easy (e), Intermediate (i), or Hard (h)");
    String diff = keyboard.next();
    diff = diff.substring(0, 1);
    String guess = "";
    String newGuess = "";
    String newWord = "loops";//RandomWord.newWord();
    int y = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < newWord.length(); i++) {
        newWord.charAt(i);
        guess = newWord.replaceAll("[^#]", "-");
    }


    if ((diff.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) || (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("i")) || (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))) {
        System.out.println("The secret word is:" + " " + newWord);
        System.out.println("The word is:" + " " + guess);

        System.out.println("Please enter the letter you want to guess");
        String letterInput = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter the spaces you want to check (seperated by spaces)");
        String spaces = keyboard.nextLine();
        spaces = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(spaces.trim().charAt(count)));

        for (int i = 0; i < spaces.trim().length(); i++) {
            int x = Character.getNumericValue(spaces.trim().charAt(i));


            if (x == 0) {
                y = x - 1;
                y = 0;
                if ((letterInput.equalsIgnoreCase(newWord.substring(x, x + 1)))) {
                    newGuess = guess.substring(0, y) + guess.substring(y, x) + letterInput + guess.substring(x + 1);
                    System.out.println(newGuess);
                }
            }
            else if ((letterInput.equalsIgnoreCase(newWord.substring(x, x + 1)))) {
                newGuess = guess.substring(0, x) + guess.substring(x, x + 1) + letterInput + guess.substring(x + 1);
                System.out.println(newGuess);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? exception or just logical error?

Comment: I just know that the logic is off, in the example I gave in the OP, the output I want is for newGuess = -oo-- but i keep getting -o---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem here is Scanner is playing with you:

Default delimiter for scanner is `white-space character` hence when you enter for options including space scanner reads only first character.

There were couple of problems with your Substring method also, I have tweaked your code a bit:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    keyboard.useDelimiter("\\n"); \\---------- this is what tells scanner to use new line char as delimiter

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter your difficulty: Easy (e), Intermediate (i), or Hard (h)");
        String diff = keyboard.next();

        String guess = "";
        String newGuess = "";
        String newWord = "loops";//RandomWord.newWord();

        int y = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < newWord.length(); i++) {
            guess = newWord.replaceAll("[^#]", "-");
        }
        if ((diff.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) || (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("i")) || (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))) {
            System.out.println("The secret word is:" + " " + newWord);
            System.out.println("The word is:" + " " + guess);

            System.out.println("Please enter the letter you want to guess");
            String letterInput = keyboard.next();

            System.out.println("Please enter the spaces you want to check (seperated by spaces)");
            String spaces = keyboard.next();

            for (String s : spaces.split("\\s")) {
                int x = Integer.valueOf(s);

                if (newWord.charAt(x) == letterInput.charAt(0)) {
                    System.out.println("Guess is correct for position " + x);
                    guess = guess.substring(0, x) + letterInput + guess.substring(x + 1, guess.length());
                    System.out.println(guess);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! You almost got there

Good luck!

Comment: Wow thanks, I'm going to have to review the Scanner class again because I completely forgot about that. Is there anyway I can just print the -oo-- without the -o---?  If so can you give me a hint or psedocode as to how to do that? (I dont want a direct answer).

Comment: I will give you a hint first ,see if you can solve,( if not I know the answer).
currently we are doing `System.out.println(guess);` for every index we check


**hint**: do `System.out.println(guess);` only once

Comment: There are many cases left to address in code, you will surely come across them. feel free to ask me as and when you are stuck. If you think this question is answered do accept the answer